# Guitar that can pick up body percussion, and what a guitar needs to do it

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, pick-ups, fingerstyle-guitar, acoustic-effects

Recently I bought an Ovation guitar, after seeing some videos of people using it for percussive guitar playing, for example 
[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdjXpdQB1JM&t=2m50s), or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shYdqbJgQdc&t=0m20s). Even talking "how sensitive and well-suited it is for this style", see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DLarpRwC8w&t=1m0s).

But after plugging mine in I discovered it does not pick up the percussion on the body.

Surely, it is another model, but as far as I can tell the Kaki king signature also just uses a Piezo like mine (it is beneath the bridge).

So I am wondering, how to see from the technical specifications if a guitar can pick up the percussive sounds from the body? And is it more the case that most guitars can not do it? What guitars do this well?

Comment: Not an answer, but an idea for you. Piezo stick on pups are very cheap, and can be stuck inside the top. Use that and you have a percussive guitar!

Comment: @Tim What exactly do you mean, when I look up piezo pick up I mostly find ones that could be packed under the bridge...

Comment: The last couple I bought were supplied with a sticky pad, to be placed wherever on a guitar - in fact, one is now on a mandolin, doing a great job! Google piezo pup, and there'll be some cheap ones which you could maybe stick under the top, and have a separate wire to feed to the amp - so the volume is controllable separately.

Answer (score 3):

Percussive guitarist Mike Dawes talks over his pickup configuration in a [Premier Guitar interview](https://youtu.be/6165kqKto3A) available on YouTube.

He has [four pickups](https://youtu.be/6165kqKto3A?t=780) and internal mics. [Overview of his pickups starts at 10:40](https://youtu.be/6165kqKto3A?t=640)

- Magnetic sound hole pickup - combines with piezo for primary sound
- Piezo under the bridge plate (not under saddle) - combines with sound hole for primary sound
- Transducer about 2" from the sound hole at about 8:00 (assuming 12:00 is the neck). This gives his kick drum effect
- Internal microphone to pick up external percussion (slapping & scratching) - ["You need an internal mic to really pick it up well"](https://youtu.be/6165kqKto3A?t=230)